# How to show full object in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

```
var functor=function(){
    //test
}

functor.prop=1;

console.log(functor);
```

this only show the function part of the functor, cannot show the properties of the functor in console.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Use `console.dir()` to output a browse-able object you can click through instead of the `.toString()` version, like this:

```
console.dir(functor);
```

> Prints a JavaScript representation of the specified object. If the object being logged is an HTML element, then the properties of its DOM representation are printed <sup>[1]</sup>

---

[1] https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-reference#dir

Comment: It should be noted that just printing `varName` in Chrome console and hitting Enter gives the same effect as `console.dir(varName)`.

Comment: @Vadzim I don't think that's true (anymore). Try it with an HTML element you selected for example.

Answer (score 126):

You might get better results if you try:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(functor));
```

Comment: this answer is great but I think doesn't work with the sample above, tried in a new tab and returns undefined

Comment: With all due respect to this answer, eventually it returns a string representing the object, and not a "browseable" object in the console, like the question is all about here. True, if you run this output string through JSON.parse, it will return to its object-format, but then the console will still show it a ".toString()" and we're back to square one. The answer here with the use of "console.dir" is the best fit for the question in hand.

Answer (score 38):

You might get even better results if you try:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
```

Comment: This answer improves on @BastiBen's by formatting the output.

Answer (score 15):

```
var gandalf = {
  "real name": "Gandalf",
  "age (est)": 11000,
  "race": "Maia",
  "haveRetirementPlan": true,
  "aliases": [
    "Greyhame",
    "Stormcrow",
    "Mithrandir",
    "Gandalf the Grey",
    "Gandalf the White"
  ]
};
//to console log object, we cannot use console.log("Object gandalf: " + gandalf);
console.log("Object gandalf: ");
//this will show object gandalf ONLY in Google Chrome NOT in IE
console.log(gandalf);
//this will show object gandalf IN ALL BROWSERS!
console.log(JSON.stringify(gandalf));
//this will show object gandalf IN ALL BROWSERS! with beautiful indent
console.log(JSON.stringify(gandalf, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 9):

this worked perfectly for me:

```
for(a in array)console.log(array[a])
```

you can extract any array created in console for find/replace cleanup and posterior usage of this data extracted

Comment: a bit more detailed: `for (i in arr) { console.log(i); console.log(arr[i]); }`

Comment: it won't output properties and methods that are not enumerable

Answer (score 5):

I made a function of the Trident D'Gao answer.

```
function print(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));
}
```

**How to use it**

```
print(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to conveniently print things to the console.

```
// function for debugging stuff
function print(...x) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(x,null,4));
}

// how to call it
let obj = { a: 1, b: [2,3] };
print('hello',123,obj);
```

will output in console:

```
[
    "hello",
    123,
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b": [
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

With modern browsers, `console.log(functor)` works perfectly (behaves the same was a `console.dir`).

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to wrap function into an array:

```
console.log( [functor] );
```