# What differs between console.log and console.dir?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between console.dir and console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log)

I have recently learnt the existence of `console.dir()`.

After looking through [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.dir), I did not clearly understand what is the real difference between this and `console.log`. They both show the same output (but `.dir` shows some properties), is that it?

Which function should I use when debugging/developping?

**EDIT:** I just found out an existing question which answers my thoughts: [What's the difference between console.dir and console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way the information is presented is different. For example, in Firebug, if I do this:

```
a = { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" };
```

And then I do:

```
console.log(a)
```

I get:

```
Object { foo="foo", bar="bar"}
```

If I do this:

```
console.dir(a)
```

I get:

```
bar    "bar"
foo    "foo"
```

If I had nested objects, I would have the little twisty controls (MDN calls them "disclosure triangles") so that I could easily dig deeper into the object properties.

Depending on the tools you are using, YMMV.

Comment: Thank you, I will rely more on `console.dir` from now on. It's quite funny that last week I was struggling with `console.log`: Chrome wouldn't show me the content of an object (nor its properties).

Comment: Thanks for a concise and clear explanation :)