# Why do I get [object, Object] when I print a jQuery selection to the console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am doing one of the most simple and fundamental things with jQuery - taking a selection from the DOM and then printing it to the console. However, all I see in the console is [object, Object]. Here is the line in my js code which prints to console the selection `console.log($(".map_id"));`

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: firefox. im gonna try chrome now.

Comment: Try `console.dir` instead of `console.log`

Comment: I always use console.log([$(".map_id")]); to get around that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.dir` logs html elements as objects. Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log)

Answer (score 1):

What king of HTML element is *$(".map_id")*?

If it's a input element you should use `$(".map_id").val()` to get the input value.
Otherwise, if it's a *div* or *p* or *span* or any other HTML tag, you should use `$(".map_id").html()` to get it contents.

Using just `$(".map_id")` will return a jQuery object relative to *".map_id"* selection, not it value or content.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion about using .html(). This fixed the problem of seeing [object, Object] in the console, but I don't know how to parse the html that I see contained in that object. I tried console.dir() and it seems to be more promising. Thanks for your help though.