# How do I view the raw data posted in a Worker.postMessage( myObject ) call?

Tags: javascript, browser, web-worker

The nice thing about the web worker `postMessage()` when sending an object, is it serializes the entire object including all elements of the object that are themselves objects. All data that is a pointer to another object comes across and is rebuilt with everything pointing at the right thing.

The problem is... making sure it only brings across what I need. I am pulling a subset of a linked list of objects where there is a lot of pointers in object to other objects. ie, it's not just child elements that are an object pointed to by just the parent object, there's a lot of relationship pointers.

Is there a way to see what the `postMessage()` copies across? Like a way to see the raw JSON?

Comment: It's not JSON. The engine will use some internal serialisation format.

Comment: Try `onmessage = console.log.bind(console);` in the Worker?

Comment: @Bergi logging it just gives me the outer variables in the object - "Object {message: 9, subMessage: 1, msgGuid: 1, pages: Array[1], success: undefined…}"

Comment: Just click on the `Array [1]` in the debugger to expand its view.

Comment: @Bergi - I understand that. My problem is the object has a tree of sub objects including possible links across to other objects. If I can get some JSON type text that makes it easy to walk through the 500+ objects in the message to see if it's just what I want.

Comment: For that, just call `JSON.stringify()` on it (or a non-cyclic part of it) before logging. Or try [`console.table`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.table) in Firebug.

Comment: @Bergi - I tried that and get an exception that it's cyclic. I tried removing the parts that I think cause the cycle, and still get that. It's frustrating because if I could get the string, then I could see what I need to do to get the string...

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I use Chrome and forgot that Chrome's console.log is different than most browsers. Try using console.dir(object).

I elaborated on the code a little too.

To log what your worker sends back to the main thread...

```
// will log what your worker is sending back to the main thread
onmessage = function (e) { console.dir(e.data); }
```

To see what the main thread is sending to the worker...

```
// The worker
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');

// Prepare message for worker
var message = {
    colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
    numbers: [1,2,3]
};

// log it
console.dir(message);

// send it
worker.sendMessage(message)
```

Also maybe check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log) out to see the difference between console.log and console.dir.

Comment: I tried that but it's just showing me the same object so I have to do the same thing, walk through all pointers.

Comment: Can you share your code? Also try to test it in chrome and let me know what happens.

Comment: I tried in Chrome and got "Object {message: 9, subMessage: 1, msgGuid: 1, pages: Array[1], success: undefined…}" for console.log(msg) and "Object" for console.dir(). The code's not sharable because there's a ton and it's proprietary. I tried to JSONify it but that gave me a no circular references error.