# How to list the prototypical properties of an array in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to see all the prototypical properties of an array [] or hash {} in Chrome's Dev Tools? I want to illustrate that each time you create a new array or hash you also get a whole slew of properties that come with that array.

For some reason console.log(Array.prototype); doesn't work for me on my Dev Tool (Linux Chrome

[image: For some reason console.log(Array.prototype); doesn't work for me on my Dev Tool (Linux Chrome)]

`console.dir(Array.prototype);` worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new array you can also view it's contents including all inherited Array.prototype properties using `console.dir()`.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.dir(arr);
```

Comment: Coming at this problem from the other side is [What's the difference between console.dir and console.log?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11954152/710446)

Comment: No need to create a new array first. `console.dir(Array.prototype);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the protypical properties of an existing array, you can use

```
console.dir(arrayName.__proto__);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

U can use console.log(Array.prototype);

[image: img]