# How to print an HTMLElement's properties to console instead if its HTML code?

Tags: javascript

Suppose the following code:

```
var a = new Image(1, 1);
a.onload = function() {
    console.log(this);
};
a.src = 'some.address.com/some/image.jpg';
```

When this image gets loaded, it will print itself to the console, but the output is an HTML element, like so:

`<img width="10" height="10" src="http://some.address.com/some/image.jpg">`

When I expect that it would print it as any other JavaScript object, something like:

[image]

Is there a way to force it to be print like this?

Comment: Try console.dir via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log

Comment: @MikeStrand Works perfectly! You can write an answer if you want :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`.  There's some variation of behavior across browsers.  More details at:
[What's the difference between console.dir and console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log)

Answer (score 2):

Force it to output an object by putting it in one:

```
var a = new Image(1, 1);
a.onload = function() {
    console.log({obj: this});
};
a.src = 'some.address.com/some/image.jpg';
```