# What attribute of a function really means

Tags: javascript

For the code below, I provide `isShiny` for an object `obj`, it is listed as part of the attribute, which is essentially a key-value pair, 
where the key is `isShiny`, 
value is the anonymous function.

But when I provide `isShiny` for a function `func`, what really happened behind the scene? When I print out a function, there is no hint of where the `isShiny` is.

```
 var obj ={} //this is an object
    obj.isShiny = function () {
        console.log(this);
        return "you bet1";
    };
    console.log(obj); 

    var func = function () {console.log(this)}; //this is a function
    func.isShiny = function () {
        console.log(this);
        return "you bet1";
    };
    console.log(func);
```

This is the output for `console.log` from browser.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add what are you expecting to have as a result? There is not a specific question at this post. Is the real question a knowledge question (e.g. how JavaScript works?) or is there an issue that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're not getting any trace of `isShiny` when you log the function is purely due to the browser's implementation of `console.log`, and not related to what's happening behind the scenes in JavaScript. `console.log` sees that the property is a function and therefore doesn't log it out like a 'normal' object. In this case, `console.dir` would likely be more useful. For more information about how `console.log` differs from `console.dir`, check out [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log).

As you have rightly realised, in JavaScript, a function is essentially nothing more than a callable object - you can assign and access properties just like any non-function object.

Answer (score 2):

Use `console.dir` instead of `console.log` and it logs the function object with it's methods and properties.

A related question: [What's the difference between `console.dir` and `console.log`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log)