# What does the `dir` in `console.dir` stand for?

Tags: javascript

I get what it does, and use it all the time. But funnily enough, I've yet to find documentation that says what "DIR" actually *means*. "Directory" doesn't seem right.

This is not a "What's the difference between `console.log()` and `console.dir()`?" question. It's simply, "What do the letters DIR actually stand for?"

Comment: Do not use it all the time. It is non-standard.

Comment: Don't think "directory" as in "folder", think "directory" as in "a listing".

Comment: I think it just means "Directory".  Directory is a synonym for index, list, listing, register, catalogue, record, archive, inventory etc.  Some of those words might have been a better fit for this function though.

Comment: This [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log) helps a little. Hard to saw what the designer intended, but it seems roughly like a "directory" of attributes of the item being displayed. As others have noted, we in the computer field have gotten used to a narrow definition of "directory" but it really is a more general term.

Comment: @BoltKey Don't worry, only for debugging.

Comment: @HaukurHaf If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: @RobertAKARobin done :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It just means "Directory". Directory is a synonym for index, list, listing, register, catalogue, record, archive, inventory etc. Some of those words might have been a better fit for this function though, like "listing".