# Accessing the DOM via chrome console

Tags: javascript, dom

Some questions regarding the DOM and what it exactly is.

When I access `document` via `console.dir` I get all the properties of `document` like this:

[image: DOM javascript]

When I do a `console.log` I get something which looks more like the DOM:

[image: DOM javascript]

### Questions:

1. In my understanding the second object which we get from `console.log()` is the DOM. and the one from `console.dir()` is the DOM and all the Javascript properties which exists on the DOM. Is this correct?
2. Is the DOM is a Javascript object?
3. Can we access the DOM structure of element nodes which we get from `console.log(window.document)` from a property of `console.dir(window.document)`?

Comment: Have look at the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log

Comment: Is it a js object. No. I mentioned that it wasn't yesterday when you were asking about logging document and someone else stated it was which is incorrect. Link in answer below clarifies this

Comment: Yes thanks for the clarification because I was kinda confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM (Document Object Model) is a generic term for a set of objects.

`document` is a DOM object; you're just seeing two different ways of representing it.

You can access the DOM hierarchy via properties like `.children`.

For more information, see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).