# How console.log works behind the scene?

Tags: javascript, console.log

When I am running this piece of code in JSEditor.

```
var obj = {}; 
console.log(obj); 
obj.foo = 'bar';
```

The o/p is : `[object Object]`

While the same code in the console tab is giving me this o/p:

```
{}
"bar"
```

Comment: I recommend [https://repl.it/languages/javascript](https://repl.it/languages/javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between console.dir and console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log)

Comment: It worked fine when I ran my code using the link you have provided. @user633183

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node js

`console` instance configured to write to `process.stdout` and `process.stderr`. 
The global [console](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_new_console_options) can be used without calling `require('console')`.

```
var p={}
```

`console.log` function uses `process.stdout.write();`[process.stdout](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)

So you will get `object` after writing the value