# Can't access list property from datalist object in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, html-datalist

This is seriously weird and it's making me crazy...

When I check the properties of the datalist, it clearly has a `list` property, but I still can't access it.

What am I doing wrong? This is impossible.

```js
let datalistElement = document.getElementById("some-id");

console.dir(datalistElement);             // Shows the element
console.log(datalistElement.list);        // null
```

Comment: Would you mind providing a reproducible example? There is not currently enough information in the question for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I'm an idiot. I am setting the datalist options via an API request, and I am trying to access them before being set... I need a rest.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` and `console.dir` behaves little different with browsers. [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954152/whats-the-difference-between-console-dir-and-console-log#11954537).

Have you tried `console.dir(JSON.stringify(datalistElement));`.

Do you still see `list` property in strirngified value?