# Getting total objects in array inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to get the length or total objects inside array.
I am creating a slickEventData object and pushing this object into eventsArray.
So i end up with an array containing objects.
I want to get the total amount of slickEventData objects inside this array.
When i use length i get the wrong number, i get the total amount of keys? not objects.

My Code

```
var slickEventData = {}
console.log(event);

slickEventData.module = "slick_module"
slickEventData.eventType = event.type;
slickEventData.leadboxId = "a"//container.getAttribute("data-leadbox-id");
slickEventData.advertId = advertId;
slickEventData.length = "length of event"
slickEventData.time = Date.now();
slickEventData.posted = "postedStatus"
eventsArray.push(slickEventData)

console.log("events Array " + JSON.stringify(eventsArray))
console.log("events Array length " + eventsArray.length)

if (!sessionStorage.events) {
  console.log("no old events found")
  sessionStorage.events = eventsArray;
  console.log(sessionStorage.events);
}

else if (sessionStorage.events) {
  var oldEvents = sessionStorage.events;
  console.log("old events length " + oldEvents.length);
  console.log("updated events array met oldData " + eventsArray);
  alert(JSON.stringify(oldEvents));
  //loop thru old events to add them to current events and add these to the sessionStorage
  //postTrackingData(sessionStorage.events);
}
//sessionStorage.events = eventsArray;// add events to storage
console.log("session = " + (JSON.stringify(sessionStorage)))
```

These are my attempts. I am guessing it is counting all the keys and values and the array as objects this returning 15 objects when i use oldEvents.length.
eventsArray.length returns the correct value.
Does adding this array into the sessionStorage.events mess this up?

How would i go about finding how many objects are inside oldEvents?

I might be doing this completely wrong

Edit:

oldEvents returns [object Object] so no multiple objects it seems
eventsArray returns [object Object],[object Object] etc. so multiple objects.

arent they supposed to return the same?
I am just adding eventsArray to the sessionStorage and then retrieving it

My goal is to keep pushing events into the sessionStorage as they happen and not loose them between refreshes.

Comment: It doesn't matter what's inside an array; the `array.length` is always going to return the number of items/objects inside that array. Are you initializing the `eventsArray` correctly?

Comment: Try to add a console.log(oldEvents) statement (no JSON.stringify). In Chrome or Firefox you will be able to browse through you array and check it's contents conveniently. Make sure the array contains what you expect.

Comment: Hmm oldEvents returns [object Object]. But eventsArray returns [object Object],[object Object] etc.

Comment: console.log(<yourObjectOrWhatever>) or .dir() should show you all the objects in a tree-like, exapandable hierarchy. This way you can exactly see what your variable contains. Use Chrome for this. Eventually you have an extra layer e.g. Array[Array[Obj,Obj]] instead of the expected Array[Obj,Obj].
Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482950/how-to-show-full-object-in-chrome-console

Comment: Yeah i think this is the problem aswell but for some reason chrome doesnt always let me expand the object like it should. i think im going to download  firebug see if that will work better. Like i said it returns [object Object] but it wont let me expand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[object object]` is what you get when you call `.toString()` on an object.

You can't expand a string in devtools. I'd take the angle of your doing some unintentional type conversion.

This `sessionStorage.events = eventsArray` and `oldEvents = sessionStorage.events` looks suspicious to me.

LocalStorage and SessionStorage only accepts key value pairs of strings. It will not stringify your objects for you, but call `.toString()` of them. I believe the issue is your not storing the stringified array into SessionStorage so when you get it out its not an array but a string, your calling `.length` of a string.

May I suggest these changes:

```
//Setting storage items
sessionStorage.setItem('events', JSON.stringify(eventsArray));

//reading storage items
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('events'));
```

---

EDIT: Whilst this may not be directly answering the question, it is still (i believe) valuable information and too big to explain in a comment.

Comment: Yes i just figured out what i was doing wrong. Now im explicitly going to stringify it before and parse it after. Since you kind of solved the problem i thought id mark this as the answer.