# How to pass array by query string from ajax to nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, pug

I am trying to pass the array with the help of query string but when i am fetching it using nodejs it act as a string.

my query string is like -

```
'/home?page='+value;

  where value is [{name : 'a'},{name :'b'},{name : 'c'}]
```

but the problem is when i send it in node js and apply

`console.log(req.query.page[0].name)` output is `[object object]`
but i want the output `a`

Please help me in this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show full object in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482950/how-to-show-full-object-in-chrome-console)

Comment: that is not working ,still get `[object object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you are sending a raw object as a parameter. Try doing `'/home?page=' + JSON.stringify(value)` and `console.log(JSON.parse(req.query.page[0].name))`.

You may also need to encode the param like so: `ecodeURI(JSON.stringify(value))`
and decode with `decodeURI`, like so: `decodeURI(req.query.page[0].name)`

Comment: thanx perfect answer.