# How to display all properties of an object in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an object, say object obj. Obj has several properties(int id, boolean status, etc) and I know I want to access some of the properties. Yet because I do not know where I defined this object, I would like to know the best way to display all the properties of the object using console.log.

Hey all, when I tried using `console.log(obj);` it did not work. That is the reason I posted this question. For some reason, in my application; it returned obj obj instead of the properties or letting me open up the properties. I haven't tried the `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));` but the command `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(intended_obj));`worked exactly as intended.

Comment: just `console.log(obj)`. any modern browser will print it in a nice way so you can navigate the properties. nb : console.log has nothing to do with angular, this is just Javascript

Comment: When I ran that, it would come back as obj obj. That's why I thought this may have been an Angular JS thing; and that's why the question was posted.

Comment: can you create a plunker or stackblitz demonstrating this ? Also, which browser are you using ?

Comment: I was using Google Chrome and also I already found the answer and posted it below.

Comment: Also, thanks for your help as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show full object in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482950/how-to-show-full-object-in-chrome-console)

Comment: You are showing object as a String data type. Pass it as Object type. If you have data as String than parse it with JSON.parse()

Comment: Use `console.dir(obj)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the correct answer is using console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(intended_obj));
This will list all the properties of the object in an array!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `console.table(obj)`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table):

```
// an object whose properties are strings
function Person(firstName, lastName){
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}

var me = new Person("John", "Smith");
console.table(me);
```

Browser's console: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` to display the proper json string of the object.