# JavaScript: console.log can it print the full (non-truncated) output of a JS event?

Tags: javascript, console.log

When I do `console.log(e)`, I get:

`PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, pointerId: 1, width: 1, …}`

Is there a way to print the full output and remove the elipsis (…)? Note: I'd like to print all the properties of an event object.

Perhaps superfluous background information, but my motivation for this is: I want to resimulate the events in a JS script that automates all the events and I want the events that I create to be exactly the same (I want to do this in vanillaJS as I can't use Selenium or those type of things for this).

Comment: Put a break-point at the event line and start typing `e.<SOMETHING>`

Comment: I am logging a massive amount of mousemove events, and I want to have all the data of the object. Hmm...

I suppose I should stringify it.

Comment: You can use `console.dir` instead of `console.log` as seen here: [_"How to show full object in Chrome console?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482950/how-to-show-full-object-in-chrome-console)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show full object in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482950/how-to-show-full-object-in-chrome-console)

Comment: I tried that before asking the question, `console.dir` didn't work in Chrome, maybe other browsers.

Comment: I tried all the answers of the previous question. I do think it's the same question, but since I want to print an event object, it's more difficult. I think I'd need to write my own logging function, and do an `Object.entries`? I wish there was default functionality for this, but I'm doubting it.

Comment: `console.table` shows an expanded object but it takes up a lot of space. Also, `console.dir` is certainly in chrome. I am using it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand it just by clicking that elipsis or the arrow at the beginning of the line. If you want to show only custom properties, try to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, '  '))`.

Comment: But I'm printing out hundreds of mousemoves at once. I am not going to click that a 100+ times.

Comment: @MelvinRoest In this case use `JSON.stringify` and print only what you need.

Comment: There are tons of practical solutions to my problem, but I figured: it should be possible to automatically print out all the values of a JS event, wouldn't it? It would be quite handy if one wants to capture all the data of it.

Comment: @MelvinRoest Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519193/230983) about how to convert an event to JSON (make sure to check the 2019 Update). By the way, I think it will be hard enough to debug such events if you will print all properties. My advice is to print only things you really need.

Comment: Yea, I will, but I'd figure that there would be some in-browser setting that you could change? My screen is half empty, since it doesn't completely fill up to the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of things, all with their own drawbacks and advantages.

I used

```
const newEvent = {};
for (var property in e) {
  newEvent[property] = e[property];
}
```

and in other cases

```
const entries = [];
for (var property in e) {
  entries.push(property);
  entries.push(e[property]);
}
```

Simply logging the entries array, yields about a 70+ key/value pairs, there were a 133 items in the array (no clue why the number was odd). It is possible to print it the array (or the object) out in JSON but it was a horrible experience, because the stringification gets ugly when you're replacing circular references (it can be done, but the formatting is not what I was looking for).

Eventually I hacked it with the following code:

```
const entries = [];
const entries2 = [];
let i = 0;
for (let property in e) {
  i++;
  if (i <= 40) {
    entries.push(property);
    entries.push(e[property]);
  }
  if (i > 40) {
    entries2.push(property);
    entries2.push(e[property]);
  }
}
console.log(i, entries, entries2);
```

The generalization of this code would chop up the array indefinitely at around 30 key/value pairs.